# JSON object to API via GET method (PHP cURL)

Tags: php, json, curl, get

I'm trying to send a JSON object using the GET method through PHP cURL (I've tried to find an answer on this for a while, but GET is unfortunately named with regards to search engine results...)

Anyway this is what I have right now:

```
function GET_CURL(){
    $api_url='https://www.example.com';
    $GETVARS=[
        'a'=>1,
        'b'=>2
    ]
    $QUERYSTRING=json_encode($GETVARS);

    $ch=curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$api_url.$QUERYSTRING);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,[
        'Content-Type: application/json'
    ]);
    return curl_exec($ch)
}
```

I guess my question would be how XMLHttpRequest handles GET requests, and how to emulate that using cURL.

Comment: You are going to need to URL-encode your query string.  Why not send via POST, that would typically be more appropriate when trying to send JSON data. What's up with all the uppercase function and variable names? Where is `$API_URL` defined (I don't see it in scope in your example)? What does this have to do with `XMLHttpRequest` (which is a javascript construct)? Why try to set `Content-Length` header when you are not sending any content (your content is in URL)?

Comment: `Why not send via POST?`: API documentation says to use `GET`
`Uppercase names`: I dunno lol, one of those days.
`$API_URL definition`: Whoops
`XMLHttpRequest`: Nothing, I just want to know how it handles data
`Content-Length`: Ok, I'll get rid of it.

Comment: and it asks for a URL-encoded JSON string to be passed as opposed to a more traditional query string?  This seems very unusual.